# Uniqueness of representations of matrix product states

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

Let $\{A_k\}_{k=1\dots N}$ and $\{B_k\}_{k=1\dots N}$ be two sets of $d\times d$ matrices over the complex numbers such that for any length $L$ and any sets of indices $\{j_1,j_2,\dots j_L=1\dots N\}$ the following trace equality holds:

$\text{Tr}(A_{j_1}A_{j_2}\dots A_{j_L})=\text{Tr}(B_{j_1}B_{j_2}\dots B_{j_L})$

This equality is obviously satisfied if there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $B_k=SA_kS^{-1}$ for all $k=1\dots N$.

Under what conditions can we guarantee that there is such an $S$ intertwiner?

Comment: do you know anything about the ring you are working over? is it a field? may we assume it is algebraically closed?

Comment: Sorry, I was only thinking about the complex numbers. Perhaps I should correct it.

Comment: This $S$ should then exist by simultaneaous jordanizing, if and only if those morphisms commute, however, your two things have nothing to do with each other, since the trace does not see conjugacion with invertible morphisms, so your conjugation with $S$ can help you to get the above identity, but it is quite the overkill

Comment: @Enkidu my understanding of your comment is "for a fixed $k$, there exists a matrix $S$ such that $B_k = SA_k S^{-1}$ if and only if $A_kB_k = B_k A_k$".  I don't really see how this addresses the question being asked.  If this isn't what you mean, then I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: in my opinion this question is just about the existence of such an $S$, hence it has nothing to do with the trace above "Under what conditions can we guarantee that there is such an S intertwiner?", and hence if you know that you need to triangularize all of the morphisms simultaneously (the $S$ should work for all $k$). So you get a quite clear characterization of those $\{A_k\},\{B_k\}$ such tht such an $S$ exists.  (There being more than two might be essential, since if you have only have $B_1=S A_1 S^{-1}$ it only fixes the Jordan type)

Comment: So alltogether, you fix $k$ Jordan types ($B_k=S^{-1}A_k S$) and all of the matrices have to be simultaneously triangulizable.
At least that Is how I would interpret the question and search for the conditions.

Comment: I don't understand: why do you suspect that such one $S$ "would work for all $k$"?

Comment: I do not! I say that for such an $S$ to exist and work for all $k$, all the $A_k$ and $B_k$ bust be simultanesously triagonalizable, and etven Jordanizable. I am not saying that $S$ can do that, I am sayin, if you want such an $S$, your $A_k,B_k$ need to be simulatneously triagonalizable. I think you are reading my claim the wrong way around.

Comment: @BalázsPozsgay I'm not sure how helpful this is, but your result makes me think of [Specht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem). I suspect that this is already an interesting question with $N = 2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87233/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-enkidu).

Comment: I don't think that they have to be triangularizable at the same time. 

By choosing all indices $j_k=a$ for lengths $L=1,\dots,d$ we can prove that the eigenvalues of $A_a$ and $B_a$ are the same. However, at this point even the Jordan types can be different for some $a$. 

In those cases when there are common invariant subspaces for all $A_k$ and some other invariant subspaces for all $B_k$, one can easily construct some triangular compositions such that the traces are equal, but the matrices can not be similar to each other.

Comment: @BalázsPozsgay Are there any further constraints on the $A_k$ and $B_k$?  Are they unitary? Positive definite?

Comment: No, nothing more.

I copy from the chat: Something quite similar is investigated in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608197 but it is not entirely clear to me what they find at the end. But their section 3.2 talks about this.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of some tips from @Omnomnomnom I found the answer. It is written in 
"Shirshov's theorem and representations of semigroups" by A. Freedman, R.N. Gupta, R.M. Guralnick. Their Corollary 2.7 on page 163 deals with this problem.

The answer is: If the matrix algebras generated by the two sets are semisimple, then there is a desired common similarity transformation. The semisimple property was the one I was looking for.

Perhaps a simpler explanation is given in "On the Unitary Similarity of Matrix Families" by Yu. A. Al'pinKh. D. Ikramov. Theorem 1 is what I needed. Here the condition is the complete reducibility, which is equivalent to the semisimple property.

Comment: I'm glad that you found your answer.  In the future, you may have more success posting a question like this on [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference?

Comment: mathoverflow, though it gets less traffic, is better suited to research-level questions